# which container from std::map or std::unordered_map is suitable for my case

Tags: c++, unordered-map, stdmap

I don't know how a red black tree works with string keys. I've already seen it with numbers on youtube and it baffled me a lot. However I know very well how unoredred_map work (the internal of hash maps). std::map stays esoterical for me, but I read and tested that if we don't have many changes in the std::map, it could beat hash maps.

My case is simple, I have a std::map of `<std::string,bool>`. Keys contains paths to XML elements (example of a key: "Instrument_Roots/Instrument_Root/Rating_Type"), and I use the boolean value in my SAX parser to know if we reached a particular element.

I build this map "only once"; and then all I do is using std::find to search if a particular "key" ("path") exists in order to set its Boolean value to true, or search the first element who has "true" as associated value and use its corresponded "key", and finally I set all the boolean values to false to guarantee that only a single "key" has a "true" boolean value.

Comment: Sounds like a std::set instead of std::map. Your definition of "the first element" may impact whether it shall be unordered or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to understand how red-black trees work in order to understand how to use a `std::map`. It's simply an associative array where the keys are in order (lexicographical order, in the case of string keys, at least with the default comparison function). That means that you can not only look keys up in a `std::map`, you can also make queries which depend on order. For example, you can find the largest key in the map which is not greater than the key you have. You can find the next larger key. Or (again in the case of strings) you can find all keys which start with the same prefix.

If you iterate over all the key-value pairs in a `std::map`, you will see them in order by key. That can be very useful, sometimes.

The extra functionality comes at a price. `std::map` is usually slower than `std::unordered_map` (though not always; for large string keys, the overhead of computing the hash function might be noticeable), and the underlying data structure has a certain amount of overhead, so they may occupy more space. The usual advice is to use a `std::map` if you find the fact that the keys are ordered to be essential or even useful.

But if you've benchmarked and concluded that for your application, a `std::map` is also faster, then go ahead and use it :)

---

It is occasionally useful to have a map whose mapped type is `bool`, but only if you need to distinguish between keys whose corresponding value is `false` and keys which are not present in the map at all. In effect, a `std::map<T, bool>` (or `std::unordered_map<T, bool>`) provides a ternary choice for each possible key.

If you don't need to distinguish between the two `false` cases, and you don't frequently change a key's value, then you may well be better off with a `std::set` (or `std::unordered_set`), which is exactly the same datastructure but without the overhead of the `bool` in each element. (Although only one bit of the `bool` is useful, alignment considerations may end up using 8 additional bytes for each entry.) Other than storage space, there won't be much (if any) performance difference, though.

If you do really need a ternary case, then you would be well-advised to make the value an `enum` rather than a `bool`. What do `true` and `false` mean in the context of your usage? My guess is that they don't mean "true" and "false". Instead, they mean something like "is an attribute path" and "is an element path". That distinction could be made much clearer (and therefore less accident-prone) by using `enum PathType {ATTRIBUTE_PATH, ELEMENT_PATH};`. That will not involve any additional resources, since the `bool` is occupying eight bytes of storage in any case (because of alignment).

---

By the way, there is no guarantee that the underlying data structure is precisely a red-black tree, although the performance guarantees would be difficult to achieve without some kind of self-balancing tree. I don't know of such an implementation, but it would be possible to use k-ary trees (for some small k) to take advantage of SIMD vector comparison operations, for example. Of course, that would need to be customized for appropriate key types.

If you do want to understand red-black trees, you could do worse than Robert Sedgewick's standard textbook on Algorithms. On the book's website, you'll find a brief illustrated explanation in the [chapter on balanced trees](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/33balanced/).

Comment: In the XML Sax parser, the parsing of attributes AND values between two element tags are not in the same "handler" and I chose to not differentiate between element paths and attribute paths in my "generic" XML parser, so std::set is not enough, I need a boolean flag. There is another solution which consists of using std::set and a string value containing the path of the authorized element, but it's more complex to code in my case trust me. I really want to understand how string keys are managed in std::map :\

Comment: @Aminos: then read the chapter from Sedgewick, it will give you an idea. (The Gnu C++ library uses parent links, which I think Sedgewick doesn't like, but the basic principles are all the same.) In essence, it's just a binary search tree, so there's not a lot to understand to see how `find` works. The red-black annotation allows the insert operation to modify the tree (by rotating the root) in order to keep the tree more or less balanced, thereby guaranteeing log N search time. By the way, why do you feel it necessary to understand the details? Is there some question you have in particular?

Comment: ...The important thing about all std:: associative containers is that every value (the key-val pair) is a separate dynamically allocated object. That allows the standard library to guarantee that once a key-val pair is inserted into the container, any reference/pointer to that value will remain valid until the value is removed from the container. The internal object is *derived from* the std::pair, allowing the library to hand you a pointer or reference to the std::pair itself while keeping the metadata private (child/parent or bucket-chain pointers, colour in the case of red-black, etc.)

Comment: it's just for my own culture ;)

Comment: @Aminos: I edited the advice in the post to deal with the use of `bool` to represent what should be a two-valued enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use std::unordered_set because you really  don't need to store this boolean flag and you also don't need to keep these xml tags in sorted order so  std::unordered_set seems to me as logical and the most efficient choice.

Comment: in my case with the algorithm I wrote, I need the boolean flag because parsing occur in 2 or 3 Xerces-C++ handlers and I don't differentiate between attributes and element values in the XML paths.

Comment: @Aminos std::unordered_map then. Inserts and lookups should work faster on it, you are usually use map when you need sorting.

Comment: @Aminos: it seems that only one bool is at `true` at a time, using an iterator on the given element seems more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, I use iterators.

Comment: Well, I insert elements only once, that's why I asked the question, I only do "look ups" and I wanted to know which is theoretically is fast in that field with that condition (a map builded only once)